# linked list, getting unwanted values

Tags: list, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list that will take the input from the user, order it, and print it out once the user inputs 0 or a negative number. Somewhere my code is adding a "0" to the begining of the print loop. 
Example: I input 1-2-3-4-5. The program then returns 0-1-2-3-4-5. 
Example2: I input 1-2-3-4-5. The program then returns 0-5-1-2-3-4. Which is also a problem for me because i eventually need to make the program order the inputed values from least to greatest. But for right now im focused on getting it to take the input 1-2-3-4-5 and print 1-2-3-4-5.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode{
  int data;   
  struct listNode *next;
};

//prototypes
void insertNode(struct listNode *Head, int x);
void printList(struct listNode *Head);
int freeList(struct listNode *Head, int x);

//main
int main(){
     struct listNode Head = {0, NULL};
     int x = 1;
     printf("This program will create an odered linked list of numbers greater"
     " than 0 until the user inputs 0 or a negative number.\n");
     while (x > 0){
           printf("Please input a value to store into the list.\n");
           scanf("%d", &x);
           if (x > 0){
           insertNode(&Head, x);
           }
     }
     printList(&Head);
     system("PAUSE");
     }

void insertNode(struct listNode * Head, int x){
     struct listNode *newNode, *current;
     newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct listNode));
     newNode->data = x;
     newNode->next = NULL;
     current = Head;
     while (current->next != NULL && current->data < x) 
     {
        current = current->next;
        }

        if(current->next == NULL){
             current->next = newNode;
        }
        else{
             newNode->next = current->next;
             current->next = newNode;
        }
}
void printList(struct listNode * Head){
    struct listNode *current = Head;
    while (current != NULL){
          if(current > 0){
               printf("%d \n", *current);
          }
          current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is another iteration in a series of questions for a linked list exercise. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239025/ordered-linked-list-printing and also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240332/print-an-ordered-linked-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a zero in the list *because you put it there:*

```
struct listNode Head = {0, NULL};
```

If you want a *quick* fix, change the line in `printList()` and anything else that processes the list from:

```
struct listNode *current = Head;
```

to:

```
struct listNode *current = Head->next;
```

This will start at the second element of the list, ignoring the one you put there to start with.

---

However, a better way is probably *not* to have that extraneous element at all:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct listNode {
    int             data;
    struct listNode *next;
};

// Prototypes (freeList removed since not defined).

void insertNode(struct listNode **pHead, int val);
void printList(struct listNode *Head);

// Main program for testing.

int main(void) {
    // List initially empty.

    struct listNode *Head = NULL;

    int x = 1;
    puts("This program will create an ordered linked list");
    puts("    of numbers greater than 0 until the user");
    puts("    enters 0, a negative number, or a non-integer.");
    for(;;) {
          puts("Please input a value to store into the list.");
          if ((scanf("%d", &x) != 1) || (x <= 0)) break;
          insertNode(&Head, x);
     }
     printList(Head);
}

void insertNode(struct listNode **pHead, int val){
    struct listNode *newNode, *current, *previous;

    // Allocate new node, should really check for failure here.

    newNode = malloc (sizeof (struct listNode));
    newNode->data = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    // Handle inserting into empty list.

    if (*pHead == NULL) {
        *pHead = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // Find node to insert before.

    current = *pHead;
    while (current != NULL && current->data < val)  {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }


    // Handle inserting at start of list.

    if (current == *pHead) {
        newNode->next = *pHead;
        *pHead = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // Handle inserting at end of list.

    if (current == NULL) {
        previous->next = newNode;
        return;
    }

    // Handle inserting somewhere inside the list.

    newNode->next = current;
    previous->next = newNode;
}

void printList (struct listNode *Head) {
    struct listNode *current = Head;

    if (current == NULL) {
        puts ("There are no numbers.");
        return;
    }

    puts ("Numbers are:");
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf ("   %d\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

There's a couple of other things I've cleaned up there as well, such as changing `*current` to the more explicit `current->data`, passing a *pointer* to the head so you can change it, and making a slight modification to the main input loop. Here's a sample run:

```
This program will create an ordered linked list
    of numbers greater than 0 until the user 
    inputs 0 or a negative number.
Please input a value to store into the list.
4
Please input a value to store into the list.
1
Please input a value to store into the list.
8
Please input a value to store into the list.
5
Please input a value to store into the list.
6
Please input a value to store into the list.
3
Please input a value to store into the list.
2
Please input a value to store into the list.
9
Please input a value to store into the list.
7
Please input a value to store into the list.
0
Numbers are:
   1 
   2 
   3 
   4 
   5 
   6 
   7 
   8 
   9
```

Answer (score 0):

In `printList` you're printing the value `*current`, which is not an integer (it's a `struct listNode`).  Your compiler probably warned you about this.

Try printing `current->data`, rather than just `*current`, and things should work.

You might also need to update your `if(current > 0)` test to be something more like `current->data > 0` if that's really what you want.

Comment: Thankyou very much. Although you said change the print statement. I changed my if statement from *current to current->data and it worked. Now that i dont have that extra 0 in here, i need to figure out how to modify the code to order the inputed values while they are being inputed.

Comment: Right, but the fact that the `printf` works is just a coincidence.  Really, you're passing it a structure in memory that contains an integer and then some other stuff, and it just so happens that it knows how to do the right thing.  If you correct the `printf` statement as well, your compiler will stop outputting warnings when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

The first item in printList() function that you are printing is the Head element of your list which contains a zero as the data.  You are getting lucky because the first element of your struct is the int data so when you dereference the pointer to current you happen to get the int at the beginning of the struct.

Actually you probably should rewrite the print function like the following:

```
void printList(struct listNode * Head){
    struct listNode *current = Head->next;
    while (current != NULL){
          printf("%d \n", current->data);
          current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`... Somewhere my code is adding a "0" to the beginning of the print loop.`

Yes, in your code the line when you first init `Head`, you introduced the `0`.
This is the line:

```
struct listNode Head = {0, NULL};
```

Say if you change the above value from 0 to 999, your code would print out 999 as the first number.

You need to handle the Head node case during insert.